# where clause subquery in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert my SQL syntax to the LINQ query , And I have a problem with a subquery.
I want to select max date-time with an Id in a table as a subquery for another select command but I don't know what's right or wrong with this below code.
what I have in Sql

```
select ap.* ,aph.Lat as 'personLat',aph.Lng as 'personLng',l.cityId,l.Lat as 'LifecenterLat',l.lng as 'LifecenterLng',l.Id as 'LifeCenterId' 
from Applicant ap
inner join ApplicantAddressHistory aph on ap.Id = aph.ApplicantId 
inner join LifePlusCenter l on aph.CityId = l.CityId 
Where ap.FamilyRoleTypeId = '82e26080-fda6-4396-946c-40d0e267f1f3'  and aph.CreatedDate in (select max(CreatedDate) from ApplicantAddressHistory
where ApplicantAddressHistory.ApplicantId = ap.Id)
order by ap.NationalityCode
```

And what I have tried in linq

```
        var innerJoinMultipleTables = from app in db.Applicant.Where(x => x.FamilyRoleTypeId == Guid.Parse("82e26080-fda6-4396-946c-40d0e267f1f3"))
                                          join aph in db.ApplicantAddressHistory on app.Id equals aph.ApplicantId         
                                          where aph.CreatedDate == db.ApplicantAddressHistory.Max(x => x.CreatedDate && x.Id=aph.Id)
                                          join l in db.LifePlusCenter on aph.CityId equals l.CityId
                                          let centerLat = l.Lat
                                          let centerLng = l.Lng
                                          orderby app.NationalityCode
                                          select new { app, aph.Lat, aph.Lng, l.CityId, l.Branch, centerLat, centerLng };
```

without this below line of code ,my linq works correctly.

```
  where aph.CreatedDate == db.ApplicantAddressHistory.Max(x => x.CreatedDate && x.Id=aph.Id)
```

I need something like this below code in Linq as a subquery

```
select max(CreatedDate) from ApplicantAddressHistory where ApplicantAddressHistory.ApplicantId = '9836CEC4-EDCB-492C-9899-DF4279210CD2'
```

I finally tried this and it workd but dont know its correct way or not?!

```
           var innerJoinMultipleTables = from app in db.Applicant.Where(x => x.FamilyRoleTypeId == Guid.Parse("82e26080-fda6-4396-946c-40d0e267f1f3"))
                                          join aph in db.ApplicantAddressHistory on app.Id equals aph.ApplicantId
                                          let rept_max = (from c in db.ApplicantAddressHistory
                                                          where c.Id == app.Id
                                                          select c.CreatedDate).Max()

                                          where aph.CreatedDate == rept_max
                                          join l in db.LifePlusCenter on aph.CityId equals l.CityId


                                          let centerLat = l.Lat
                                          let centerLng = l.Lng
                                          orderby app.NationalityCode
                                          select new { app, aph.Lat, aph.Lng, l.CityId, l.Branch, centerLat, centerLng };
```

Comment: I have one question about the LINQ query: Is the sub query where statement is using the correct `ApplicantAddressHistory` column to get the maximum date?
I'm thinking this should be the correct one: `where c.ApplicantId  == app.Id`

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how it works in Linq, but you can modify your query like below to get latest details as per CreatedDate for each ApplicantId.

```
select ap.* ,aph.Lat as 'personLat',aph.Lng as 'personLng',l.cityId,l.Lat as 'LifecenterLat',l.lng as 'LifecenterLng',l.Id as 'LifeCenterId' 
from Applicant ap
inner join 
    (select *
    from
    (select *,row_number() over(partition by ApplicantId order by CreatedDate desc) rw
    from ApplicantAddressHistory
    ) p
    where p.rw=1
    ) aph 
    on ap.Id = aph.ApplicantId 
inner join LifePlusCenter l 
    on aph.CityId = l.CityId 
Where ap.FamilyRoleTypeId = '82e26080-fda6-4396-946c-40d0e267f1f3'  
/*
and aph.CreatedDate in (
select max(CreatedDate) from ApplicantAddressHistory
where ApplicantAddressHistory.ApplicantId = ap.Id
)
*/
order by ap.NationalityCode
```

Comment: I didn't have any problem in SQL But in linq

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up to :

```
            var z = from app in db.Applicant
                    join aph in db.ApplicantAddressHistory on app.Id equals aph.ApplicantId
                    join l in db.LifePlusCenter on aph.CityId equals l.CityId

                    let createDate = app.ApplicantAddressHistory.Max(c => c.CreatedDate)

                    where createDate.HasValue && aph.CreatedDate == createDate

                    && app.FamilyRoleTypeId == Guid.Parse("82e26080-fda6-4396-946c-40d0e267f1f3")
                    let personLat = aph.Lat
                    let personLng = aph.Lng
                    let centerId = l.Id
                    let LifecenterLat = l.Lat
                    let LifecenterLng = l.Lng
                    orderby app.NationalityCode
                    select new { app, aph, l, app.Id, l.CityId, centerId, personLat, personLng, LifecenterLat, LifecenterLng };
```